# Display top 5 array elements using array index

Tags: php, arrays

I have a `$active_asset_id = 33` and I have an array as

```
$media_asset_id  = array("22", "21", "23","33", "43", "55");

$ex = array_search($active_asset_id, $media_asset_id);
```

it will return the index of matching element.

Based on the index, I need to display the top 3 elements, referring to that matching index.

How to do that in php? Any built in functions are available?

For example:

if 33 matches in media_asset_id  array, I need a list of 22,21,23 ids

Comment: Please define "the top 3 elements". Do you mean the previous 3 in index order?

Comment: I'm also struggling to understand what you mean by _"the top 3 elements"_. If the active asset would be `43`, what are you expecting then? The same result or `21, 23, 33`? Or are you then expecting more values?

Comment: @Sushma I think you are confusing `top 3` with `first 3`. It should be `first 3` according to your question.

Comment: ...and the title says top 5 while the question says top 3.

Comment: previous 3 in index order

Comment: if it is a 43 then i need to display 21 23 33

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case, you can use [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

```
$media_asset_id  = array("22", "21", "23","33", "43", "55");

$active_asset_id = "33";
$ex = array_search($active_asset_id, $media_asset_id);

print_r(array_slice($media_asset_id, 0, $ex));  

// outputs
//  Array
//  (
//      [0] => 22
//      [1] => 21
//      [2] => 23
//  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use for loop to display the data before the given index like below. which can display only top 3 values from the array.

```
<?php
$active_asset_id = 55;
$media_asset_id  = array("22", "21", "23","33", "43", "55");

$ex = array_search($active_asset_id,$media_asset_id  );

$counter = 1;
for($i =0; $i <=$ex; $i++){
    if($counter == 4){
        break;
    }
    echo $media_asset_id[$i];
    $counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) will do.

```
$active_asset_id = 33;
$media_asset_id  = array("22", "21", "23","33", "43", "55");

$ex = array_search($active_asset_id,$media_asset_id  );
$finalList = array_slice($media_asset_id, 0, $ex);
print_r($finalList);
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives the 3 elements preceding the found needle. If there are less preceding elements, it will give all the preceding elements from index 0.

```
$media_asset_id = array("22", "21", "23","33", "43", "55");
$ex             = array_search('33', $media_asset_id);

if(false !== $ex)
{
  $c = $ex < 3 ? $ex : 3;
  var_dump(array_slice($media_asset_id, $ex-$c, $c));
}
```

Or you can simply do

```
if(false !== $ex = array_search('21', $media_asset_id))
  var_dump(array_slice(array_slice($media_asset_id, 0, $ex), -3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the simplest one code

```
    $active_asset_id = 33;
    $media_asset_id  = array("22", "21", "23","33", "43", "55");
    $ex = array_search("33", $media_asset_id);
    $arr  =  array_slice($media_asset_id,0, $ex); // Additional Line
    print_r($arr);
```

Output:
Array ( [0] => 22 [1] => 21 [2] => 23 )